# Effective mass convergence

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, effective-mass

What's the point of using extremely denser k-grid for extracting curvature effective masses? I saw in some publications that they use extremely dense k-grid for band structure calculations for reliable effective masses. However, in some publications they just extract effective masses from a band structure that determined with relatively coarse k-grid. I could not find so many information about effective mass convergence. Is it something really reliable? Thanks for your comments

Comment: +1 but what do you mean by "different" question? Where is the first one? Why are you using an [unregistered](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/270/5) account?

Comment: By different question I mean it's an unique question that was not asked before. I saw that I can ask a question as a guest and I saw that it was easy

Comment: I think that as the effective mass is calculated numerically from the second derivative of E with respect to k, a better quality for E(k) will imply a better calculated effective mass.

Answer (score 5):

The effective mass is related to the second derivative of the E-k curve as

[image: eff mass]

So an accurate value of effective mass requires an accurate dispersion curve at all k points. If enough k values are not taken to plot the curve, plotting tools will interpolate the values to have a smooth curve, and the values may vary significantly from the actual values. This may lead to an inaccurate value of effective mass in those regions of brillouin zone.